# for loop encounter return statement in recursion method

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, trie

```
public void delete(String key) {
    root = delete(root, key, 0);
}

public Node delete(Node x, String key, int d) {
    if(x == null) 
        return null;
    if(d == key.length())
        x.val = null;
    else {
        char c = key.charAt(d);
        x.next[c] = delete(x.next[c], key, d + 1);
    }

    //----------------
    if(x.val !=null ) 
        return x;
    for (char c = 0;c < R ; c++ ) {
        if(x.next[c] != null)
            return x;
        return null;
    }
}
```

from BOOK Algoritm 4, TrieST.java

So what's happening? `for` loop can return `x` by many times; is it okay for return type method?  If okay, then what is the final return value?

Comment: This looks like a typo. If the for loop always returns in the first iteration, you don't need a loop.

Comment: what's the meaning of typo? type?

Answer (score 0):

Once "return" is called, the function is terminated.

So the value returned by the function is either:

- *x* if *x.val != null*
- *x* if for the first *c* (ie c = 0), *x.next[c] !=null*
- *null* otherwise

As said in the comments, there must be a typo, I guess

```
return null;
```

should be after the for loop. Then the function would return:

- *x* if *x.val != null*
- *x* if there is a *c* for which *x.next[c] !=null*
- *null* otherwise